# Retrieving Youtube Asset reports via API

Tags: api, youtube, report, assets

I'm pretty sure this is possible, but its been years since I last saw the innards of this.

Right now, I can get my report by logging in to youtube.com and downloading a csv:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4mGy.png)

But I want to download these reports automatically with a script on a server.  I tried wgeting the link above, and understandably got 403 Forbidden.  I know at the bare minimum that I need a secret id and key.

What I don't know is: where to get those secrets with respect to the asset report, and which api to hit.

Any pointers/clues are welcome!